# Heroku Foreman exits with an error code 5

Tags: node.js, heroku, express, foreman

```
15:05:09 web.1  | started with pid 4888
15:05:10 web.1  | 
15:05:10 web.1  | > finext_server@0.0.1 test F:\Projects\finext\server
15:05:10 web.1  | > set NODE_ENV=development && node ./bin/www.js
15:05:11 web.1  | 
15:05:12 web.1  | exited with code 5
15:05:12 system | sending SIGKILL to all processes
15:05:12        | app.get('env'): development
```

This is the output I get, and it is a little variable in terms of the code that gets executed after SIGKILL. Sometimes, a few more lines of coide get executed before I see the command prompt again.

I tried using node-foreman, and my application works fine there. So i am guessing it has something to do with foreman. My code and procfile can be found here: https://github.com/chintanp/finext

This is the reason that the process cannot start on heroku as well.

Someone in another world had a similar problem. [Express Hello World -- Heroku Foreman Returns Code 5, 'npm start' works just fine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30064959/express-hello-world-heroku-foreman-returns-code-5-npm-start-works-just-fin)

Comment: Are you sure that's how your Procfile should look like ?

Answer (score 0):

In Procfile try this:

```
web: node app.js
```

Answer (score 0):

I recently faced exactly the same situation as you when running my application:

- foreman logged the messages "exited with code 5" and "sending SIGKILL to all processes".
- My app worked fine if I used npm ("npm start") or node-foreman ("nf start") instead of foreman.

The app also worked using [forego](https://github.com/ddollar/forego), a go application written by the author of foreman.

But a couple of weeks ago heroku added the new command "[heroku local](https://devcenter.heroku.com/changelog-items/692)", which  uses forego behind the scenes, and formally supersedes the use of foreman:

> Starting today, new Heroku Toolbelt installs will not come with
>   Foreman. ***The command heroku local has replaced foreman.*** Heroku Local
>   makes use of Forego to accomplish its tasks and it’s faster and has
>   better cross-platform support.

Note that heroku also now state that foreman is "[not officially supported](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-local)".

So the way to resolve your problem is:

- Stop using foreman.
- Download and install the latest version of heroku toolbelt.
- Replace "foreman start" with "heroku local".

This approach worked for me on Windows 7.